# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'bool' has no instance method 'call'. Receiver: true Tried calling: call() The relevant error-causing widget was Home

Tags: flutter

The following error occurred while cloning Instagram. If the if statement is removed, the output is normal, but if an if statement is added, an error occurs. I can't get a hold of it at all.

The error message as below.
Class 'bool' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: true
Tried calling: call()

My code is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './style.dart' as style;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: style.theme,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var tab = 1;
  var data = [];

  getData() async {
    var result = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://codingapple1.github.io/app/data.json'),
    );
    var result2 = jsonDecode(result.body); //jsonDecode(): json을 list나 map자료로 변환
    setState(() {
      data = result2;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Instagram',
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
            onPressed: () {},
            iconSize: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Home(data: data),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        onTap: (i) {
          setState(() {
            tab = i;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: '홈'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined), label: '샵'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key, this.data}) : super(key: key);
  final data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 380,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network(data[index]['image'], width: 300),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '좋아요 ${data[index]['likes']}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(data[index]['user']),
                      Text(data[index]['content']),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text('로딩중임');
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Class 'bool' has no instance method 'call'. Receiver: true

isNotEmpty is a property, not a method, replace `isNotEmpty()` to `isNotEmpty` and will work fine

Comment: Oh...you're my god... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First delete this lines because we will call getData into futureBuilder

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

then make your listview.builder into futureBuilder with getData() function
data with snapshot and replace  isNotEmpty() with hasData like the code below

```
FutureBuilder(
future: getData(),  
builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.data.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 380,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network(snapshot.data[index]['image'], width: 300),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '좋아요 ${snapshot.data[index]['likes']}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(snapshot.data[index]['user']),
                      Text(snapshot.data[index]['content']),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text('로딩중임');
    }
  }
```